# How to get the variable , or the variable name when from validate function of validation factory

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, annotations

I am using the javax.validation and annotations to validate the data assigned to an object of a specific class.

```
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    // create the string list to add the possible validation error
    List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();

    // validate the object and get a set of Objects that hold the errors
    Set<ConstraintViolation<AbstractTracker>> violations = validator.validate(this);

    // is errors exist add loop through the set of Object and add the errors one by one to the errorlist
    if(!violations.isEmpty()){              
        for (ConstraintViolation<AbstractTracker> violation : violations){
            result.add("RecordID: "+ recordID + " Error is " +violation.getMessage());
        }   
    }
    return result;
```

I am using a list to add all errors but i want to know the specific variable that is associated with each errorMessage.

The recordID is one variable that is giving me the the id of the record that is validated in general. I am asking for each annotated variable inside the Object with the same recordID.

Is there any way to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used something else:

I got all the declared fields and iterate on them using

```
validator.validateProperty(this, field.getName())
```

function. So i know the fields and i get an array with all violations at once

Comment: If you have one of the field that is validated recursively (because it is not a basic type), you'll get the name of the field for every validation error that happens inside this object. Be sure to iterate on all private fields of the object and its parent classes too.

Answer (score 1):

`ConstraintViolation` contains this method :

```
/**
 * @return the property path to the value from {@code rootBean}
 */
Path getPropertyPath();
```

A call to `violation.getPropertyPath().toString()` should give you what you are looking for.